# Как запустить java класс на Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish

Как запустить java класс на `Glassfish` после деплоя? Есть вариант запускать java класс через `EJB Timer`, но это шедулер и не хотелось бы его использовать...

Есть такой тип `Application Client`. Он также может быть в составе `Enterprise Application`, но ни самостоятельно, ни в составе энтерпрайз приложения  `main(String[] args)` не запускается.

Запускать через `EJB Client` не подходит. Какие еще есть возможности?

Answer (score 1):

Если подключен JSF можно используя аннотации сделать так:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped(eager = true)
public class Test{

   @PostConstruct
   private void init() {
      // do ...
   }

}
```

Также это можно сделать используя CDI [ссылка](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jsf-eager-cdi-beans.html)